# What is the right way to send a request to NSE Option Chain API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Currently I have this code to send the request:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.1 Safari/605.1.15','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br','Accept-Language': 'en-US'}

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY"

res = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```

But when I execute the last line, it either hangs for a long time, or just gives 401 error.
I tried other variations of headers, but still not getting the correct response.
Just pasting the above url in the browser, gives the json object painlessly.
Also if I try the above code from an online python tool, I'm sometimes getting the needed o/p. Does this mean I'll be able to get this working only when I host it on a trusted domain or something?

Comment: I don't see it working even in browser. Where did you find this API endpoint? Is there documentation?

Comment: @QHarr I found it in some post here on stack overflow, where I’m still not allowed to comment on. But it shows up for me on browser.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection':'keep-alive',
    'Cookie':'AKA_A2=A; ak_bmsc=2C30C88FD1C6BEED087CCD02E7643772~000000000000000000000000000000~YAAQPvASAr+cI2F6AQAAk6+tdQxncocfEFby+qeRnNu3MgRblj1MWVtVy+W1Stx/CNaRaf9PhfVoT568zV8qztByVrxV+WfdrCN2nXU0nToPdEoaZFeZ7irUu8aSUXcln/sou0taKkr1gjmS3f6faZs+Rv8LA32eUAtlTD+GgYL0OKTJ44qVVinDxeeaVOiLxzQaiv0YjRCLcovFhO7jVBCJhNeXzgOeUYCLjkOg+2DEnRaF1Cd85f83pkjjieOFpjvywz20ImVWy1fr+S2nEDqmcgKZdhjHPfJ76+Z3bvVB/Kyv2dH7J8BMjlVf7kxyGbmot54yxchJNEMs0A/QTkeow2Xa54IcGZo/RUxGRu90SFu6VpfcxLaVOdN9EbvhcNs//OPA1jhDm9Nf4A==; bm_sv=BB4B29FC4D88791AABD65B43FACB0AF7~ObLG1UzBN4vOInl5m0vWqjOpZUXtLDHJDxr92uXdHHp5bjKjrEMMJcJRzS5VY5lkIs3N7JH+gZtoTnYIWKFqPZFhFC8Oo+sjmZLrin4taKkPfpvp7RdbqySQh6BLQwbWg3UgQJUQN29H0q9MJN6FuaW2b2i13zn5CmZUSDSpJVo=',
    'Host':'www.nseindia.com',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest':'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode':'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site':'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User':'?1',
    'TE':'trailers',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0',
}

r = requests.get('https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY', headers=headers)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: If it don't work you should change the cookie in the header